# How to have a field display without a decimal

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-template

I have three fields in the subject line, the last 3, that are displaying the numbers with a decimal.  The fields are rollup summaries.  How can I get it so it doesn't show the decimal?

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="User"
     relatedToType="Opportunity"
     subject=" {!relatedTo.Account.Name} - Due: {!relatedTo.Date_Due__c}, {!relatedTo.Total_Eligible__c} Eligible, {!relatedTo.Dent_Insured_Lives_Quoted__c} Dental Lives, {!relatedTo.Vis_Insured_Lives_Quoted__c} Vision Lives" >
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >  
        <html>
            <body>
                <STYLE type="text/css">
                    TH {font-size: 14px; font-face: arial;background: #CCCCCC; border-width: 1;  text-align: center } 
                    TD  {font-size: 14px; font-face: verdana } 
                    TABLE {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 2}
                    TR {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 2}
                </STYLE>
                <font face="arial" size="3">
                    <table border="0" >
                        <tr > 
                            <th>   Quote Number   </th><th>   Contribution Type   </th><th>   Current Carrier   </th><th>   In Network   </th><th>   Out of Network   </th>
                        </tr>
                        <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!Relatedto.R00N30000001MeIXEA0__r}">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{!cx.Quote_Number_Holder__c} </td>
                                <td>{!cx.Contribution_Type__c}</td>
                                <td>{!cx.Current_Carrier__c}</td>
                                <td>{!cx.In_NetworkDiag_Prev__c}/ {!NullValue(cx.In_Network_Basic__c,"0")}/ {!NullValue(cx.In_Network_Major__c,"0")}/ {!NullValue(cx.In_Network_Ortho__c,"0")}; {!cx.In_Network_Deductible_Ind__c}/ {!cx.In_Network_Deductible_Fam__c} Ded; {!NullValue(cx.In_Network_Annual_Max__c,0)} Max; {!cx.In_Network_Ortho_Max__c}</td>
                                <td>{!cx.Out_Network_Diag_Prev__c}/ {!NullValue(cx.Out_Network_Basic__c,"0")}/ {!NullValue(cx.Out_Network_Major__c,"0")}/ {!NullValue(cx.Out_Network_Ortho__c,"0")}; {!cx.Out_Network_Deductible_Ind__c}/ {!cx.Out_Network_Deductible_Fam__c} Ded; {!cx.Out_Network_Annual_Max__c} Max; {!NullValue(cx.Out_Network_Ortho_Max__c,0)} </td>
                            </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>                 
                    </table>
                    <p />
                </font>
            </body>
        </html>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody> 
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: Use outputText with apex:param

Comment: @RahulSharma how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FLOOR` to omit decimals

```
<apex:outputText value="{!FLOOR(sObj.decimal_field__c)}"/>
```

If the decimal_field__c value is `12.00` or `12.01` or `12.99`,

> It will show `12`

Answer (score 1):

By Using `<apex:outputText>` you will able solve your problem....
Let say you want show `In_Network_Major__c` field without decimal value then to need use outputtext with below format:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!floor(In_Network_Major__c)}"/>
```

Comment: If I wanted to do it for {!relatedTo.Total_Eligible__c} would it be <apex:outputText value="{!floor(relatedTo.Total_Eligible__c)}"/>